# How to test custom hooks with event listener inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, listener

I'm using react native and jest to create my tests. I'm facing problems to test an event listener that listens to url events from **expo-linking**. This event listenner is inside an useEffect hook.

Below is the code from my custom hook with my useEffect and an event listener inside:

```
useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    Linking.addEventListener('url', async () => {
      try {
        if (!navigation.isFocused() || !isMounted.current) return;

        setIsLoading(true);

        const response = await api.get('sessions/auth/success');

        if (!response.data) return;

        console.log('aqui');

        const { notRegisteredUser, token } = response.data;

        api.defaults.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

        if (notRegisteredUser && token) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          navigation.navigate('BirthDateScreen');

          dispatch(
            updateUser({
              ...notRegisteredUser,
            }),
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('Error', `${translate('loginRegisterError')}: `, err);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [dispatch, navigation]);
```

In my test file I have the following mocks:

```
jest.mock('expo-linking', () => {
  return {
    addEventListener: (event: string, callback: () => void) => callback(),
  };
});

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  return {
    useNavigation: () => ({
      isFocused: mockedNavigationFocus,
      navigate: mockedNavigation,
    }),
  };
});

jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  return {
    useDispatch: jest.fn(),
  };
});

jest.mock('../../../store/modules/user/actions', () => {
  return {
    updateUser: jest.fn(),
  };
});

jest.mock('i18n-js', () => {
  return {
    locale: 'en',
    t: () => 'any key',
  };
});
```

Finally this is how my test looks in my first try:

```
it('should pass the test', async done => {
  mockedNavigationFocus.mockImplementation(() => true);

  apiMock.onGet('sessions/auth/success').reply(200, {
    notRegisteredUser: { name: 'Logan' },
    token: '123',
  });

  render(<LoginScreen />);

  
  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith('BirthDateScreen'),
  );

  done();
});
```

In my second try this is how my test looked (I used renderHooks from **@testing-library/react-hooks**):

```
it('should pass the test', async ()  => {
  mockedNavigationFocus.mockImplementation(() => true);

  apiMock.onGet('sessions/auth/success').reply(200, {
    notRegisteredUser: { name: 'Logan' },
    token: '123',
  });


  const { result, waitForValueToChange } = renderHook(() => useLoginButton());

  const { isLoading } = result.current;

 
  await waitForValueToChange(() => isLoading);
  await waitForValueToChange(() => isLoading);

  expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith('BirthDateScreen');

});
```

With both tests I get the following error:
[test error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1WyJ.png)

Another error I get is that my callback function inside useEffect runs many times before it stops and this does not happen when I am not testing.

Does anyone knows how can I write this test?